# Delphi: How to make ENTER key works as TAB key in TFrame

Tags: delphi

I have a Frame and some controls on them (edits, buttons, etc.). How to intercept pressing of ENTER key anywhere on a frame control and translate in to TAB key (taking into account SHIFT status)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some example code that would handle a message on the frame to be able to navigate to the next control when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. Note that this sample does not modify the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to become a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Instead it selects the next control and prevents further processing of the key down message.

Also note that the code may require further tweaking. One for, if any of the controls actually need to process the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, for instance a `TMemo`, you need to add an exception. Second for, the navigation is wrapped in the frame, i.e. after the last frame control the first frame control is focused - not a control on the form and not on the frame. For these, you might want to add conditions for the message return, if you want default processing on some condition simply call inherited without doing any other thing.

```
type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    ...
  protected
    procedure CMChildKey(var Message: TCMChildKey); message CM_CHILDKEY;
  end;

..

procedure TFrame2.CMChildKey(var Message: TCMChildKey);
begin
  if Message.CharCode = VK_RETURN then begin
    SelectNext(Screen.ActiveControl, not Bool(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) and $80), True);
    Message.Result := 1;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: This is fine if your frame only ever appears on a form on which the only controls that can receive focus are the ones on that single frame. If you are in that very specific situation, then this answer is fine. In a more general situation you need the code to live on the form. Well, you could try to make it work elsewhere but why? The form is the right place for it.

Comment: It was a strange behaviour. On the frame there is TScrollBox where some TLabel and TEdit controls are placed. I've attached the proposed code to frame, and, when I press ENTER, the focus changed from first TEdit to last one and then it was disapeared! I need to press ENTER key four or five times only after that it appeared again in first TEdit. What is the problem? Where focus is moved, to the parents: TScrollBox, TFrame, TForm?

Comment: @user - The focus shouldn't move to them unless they have their `TabStop` set. Don't know really, putting a scrollbox into my simple test frame, I couldn't duplicate it.

Comment: My frame has coтtrols over that other controls have been created and hide them. So focus jump to invisible (overlapped) controls. Now problem has solved.

Answer (score 8):

All you need is to modify the handling of `CM_DIALOGKEY`.

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey); message CM_DIALOGKEY;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if Message.CharCode=VK_RETURN then
    Message.CharCode := VK_TAB;
  inherited;
end;
```

Well, it's pretty obvious what this does and how it works.

You ask how to do this in a frame. It's not possible to handle dialog navigation in a frame. That's done by the form for fairly obvious reasons. So you'll need somehow to splice this code into the form that hosts your frame.

For a memo control this will have no effect. They will treat pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> as input of a line break. But I presume that's what you would wish to happen. Otherwise the memo control would be completely unusable.

Comment: It's a pitty that it is not possible in a frame. But I'm understand the reason, if a form has many frames on it, it is necessary to write only one event handler for all of them. Thank you!

Comment: The reason is really that if the focus is on the last control in one frame, then TAB needs to move to the first control in the next frame. And since each frame is isolated, then the frame cannot be in charge of that. Only the form can see the big picture of all the controls that are on it. And that's why `CM_DIALOGKEY` is sent to the parent form.

Comment: Yes. I'm understand. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer--it's exactly what I needed when I went searching for a solution to my problem. I've hooked into OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress before, but I've got multiple frames on multiple tabs of a page control and my tried-and-true methods just weren't working. Hooking into the CMDialogKey event of the form is what I needed!

Comment: You always provide the best answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of "drop and forget" components to do it, for example on http://Torry.net

For instance, such a component was part of RxLib and later was inherted in JediVCL with [`TJvEnterAsTab`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvEnterAsTab) name.

Comment: I think it is irrational to use a component for the task that can be written in some lines of code.

Comment: depends on POV. component centralizes the code and puts the burden of maintenance on someone else. But the choice is yours as ever, i just noticed that you have one.