# Why is VK_RETURN not passed to Form OnKeyPress event in subordinated form?

Tags: delphi, enter, onkeypress, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a `TEdit` on my main form, and on a secondary form, where I want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to call a procedure.

In both forms, I used the `OnKeyPress` event, but it only works in the main form.

In the secondary form, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> performs a <kbd>Tab</kbd> action, and neither form's `OnKeyPress` nor Edit's `OnKeyPress` events are called.

I tested in `Show()` and `ShowModal()`, the secondary form with or without `OnKeyPress`.

This was no surprise for me, since in the main form the Edits's `OnKeyPress` is activated before the form's `OnKeyPress`.

Is there any option of a `TForm` that automates the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as a <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delphi: How to make ENTER key works as TAB key in TFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340412/delphi-how-to-make-enter-key-works-as-tab-key-in-tframe)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I overlooked, that there was an OnDialogKey merged, that performed this action